Difference between RLS and WHERE condition (e.g. in views)
Is there an functional advantage or performance penalty in using RLS on table vs. using a condition on a view of such table (while hiding the table)?
It seems to me, than rather than using RLS on a table, which is later needed in some views anyway, the views can be limited in their where condition, while not granting any direct access to the table.
Is there any general recommendation on where to choose RLS and where NOT to choose RLS in favour of traditional condition?

The differences between row-level security and a view with an appropriate WHERE condition are:

restrictions in a view definition don't apply when you query the underlying table directly

row-level security can specify a policy for data modifications, without the need to specify a trigger


Note that a view that restricts access to the underlying data is only secure if you set the security_barrier option.
I agree with your suspicion that in many cases it might not matter much whether you are using a security_barrier view or row-level security. In such cases, just use what is more natural or simpler for the use case at hand.

Thank you for clarifying my suspicion.
